# Cannot Browse the Internet after Connect to VPN

Tags: internet, vpn, browsing

My employer has a client that require me to access the web through VPN connection using AT&T Global Network client for Windows. My OS is Win 7.

I have all the access such as VPN, URL and so on. However, till now I still cannot access the URL that the client gave. I asked the client, but they said everything it is okay. I know when I connect to the VPN it means my internet connection is dead except one. However, the client said that I must connect to VPN in order to access the URL they gave to login, but I still cannot access it with or without VPN connection.

The question is what should I do, I'm not an expert in IT.

Comment: Did you create a VPN first or are you just trying to connect direct to the URL?

Comment: Which VPN implementation? It matters.

Answer (score 1):

Some VPN clients, *intentionally* cut off direct routing and allow *only* routing to the VPN. I know at least about the Cisco VPN. This is done for security reason. If the direct connection is not cut, the computer would act as router into the private network and could compromise it's security.

If you can access internet from the private network you are connecting to via a proxy, just configure that proxy.